# NHibernate Linq provider and take() skip() with eager fetching

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I've got this simple linq query in NHibernate 3.2 and SQLite provider:

```
var all = (from book in Session.Query<Book>() select book)
    .Skip(15)
    .Take(15)                
    .ToList();
```

This query returns correctly 15 entities, but when I try to eager load a dependent collection with FetchMany like this:

```
var all = (from book in Session.Query<Book>() select book)
    .FetchMany(books => books.Authors)
    .Skip(15)
    .Take(15)                
    .ToList();
```

I get only 11 entities returned. Is this a bug or something I'm missing?

Here is the resulting SQL query

```
select
     book0_.Id as Id2_0_,
     author2_.Id as Id0_1_,
     book0_.Title as Title2_0_,
     book0_.Sort as Sort2_0_,
     book0_.TimeStamp as TimeStamp2_0_,
     book0_.PubDate as PubDate2_0_,
     book0_.Series_Index as Series6_2_0_,
     book0_.Author_Sort as Author7_2_0_,
     book0_.Isbn as Isbn2_0_,
     book0_.Lccn as Lccn2_0_,
     book0_.Path as Path2_0_,
     book0_.Flags as Flags2_0_,
     book0_.Uuid as Uuid2_0_,
     book0_.Has_Cover as Has13_2_0_,
     book0_.Last_Modified as Last14_2_0_,
     author2_.Name as Name0_1_,
     author2_.Sort as Sort0_1_,
     author2_.Link as Link0_1_,
     authors1_.book as book0__,
     authors1_.author as author0__
from 
    books book0_ 
  left outer join 
    books_authors_link authors1_ on book0_.Id=authors1_.book left outer join authors author2_ 
  on authors1_.author=author2_.Id
order by book0_.Id asc
limit 15 /* @p0 */ offset 0 /* @p1 */
```

This effectively limits the result set to 15 rows and not 15 entities as I intended to.

Comment: Sounds like NHibernate is generating an inner join when it should be generating a left join. I'd take an extra look at the mappings for the property Authors.

Comment: I guess, this is not the problem because I have at least one author for every book. And when fetching the authors in a foreach loop for every book, I get correct results.

Comment: The interesting thing is, I do get 15 rows returned, but only 11 entities. Two books have two authors and one book has three authors. Am I correct that skip and take should limit the number of returned entities and not rows?

Comment: The behavior does indeed look a bit strange. One would assume from the Linq query that the limit should apply to books, but the query limits the number of combinations which results in fewer books. The only fix I can see is to put an AsEnumerable() after FetchMany() and before Skip() but hard to estimate what that would do to performance.

Comment: Thks Joachim. This does work indeed, but it loads all the books and filters the result in memory. This is what I intended to prevent by introducing paging in the first place. I don't know if this strange behaviour is due a problem with the nHibernate Sqlite driver or something else. I'll try another database and post the results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

skip and take are translated to the equivalents in sql which limit on rows and since you are eager fetching with joins there isn't much you can do about it.

to eager fetch the first 15 books you need to:

```
var all = Session.Query<Book>()
    .Skip(15)
    .Take(15)                
    .ToList();

var ids = all.Select(b => b.Id).ToList();

// fetch all Authors of the books, now the books in all have initialized Authors
Session.Query<Book>()
    .Where(b => ids.Contains(b.Id))
    .FetchMany(books => books.Authors)
    .List();
```

this has 2 roundtrips though

Update: one roundtrip with QueryOver, maybe you can translate into Linq

```
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Book>()
    .Skip(15)
    .Take(15)
    .Select(b => b.Id);

var all = Session.QueryOver<Book>()
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(b => b.Id).In(subquery)
    .Fetch(books => books.Authors).Eager
    .ToList();
```

Comment: After pondering about the problem, I came to the same conclusion, though it's a pity. One would expect to get 15 books when specifying take(15) and setting the Query to be of generic type Book. I tried to construct a sql statement which would do this but couldn't think of a solution. So it will be two queries, then.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = session.QueryOver<EmployeeDetails>()
                                  .Where(x => x.Salary > 2000)
                                  //.Take(2)
                                  .Skip(2)
                                  .Take(2)
                                  .List();
                //if take is before skip then it will skip the last (mentioned digits) rows
                //if take is after skip then it will skip the first (mentioned digits) rows
```